# how to write update function with this database in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

im trying to write an update function for order and product

i have this database :
-orders table:
id  status  user_id  resturant_id  created_at  updated_at

-product table:
id  name  price  resturant_id  created_at  updated_at

-order_product:
order_id  product_id  created_at  updated_at

there is many to many between order table and product table

```
 public function createOrder(Request $request)
   {
        $order = new Order;
        $order->status = $request->status;
        $order->user_id = $request->user_id;  
        $order->resturant_id = $request->resturant_id;  

        $order->save();
        $product = Product ::find($request->products);
        $order->product()->attach($product);

         return 'Success';
    }
public function UpdateOrder(Request $request , $id){

    $order =  Order::find($id);
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->user_id = $request->user_id;  
    $order->resturant_id = $request->resturant_id; 

    $order->update();
    $product = Product ::find($request->products);
    $order->product()->sync($product);

}
```

## this is request

```
  {
   "status":" not ready",
   "user_id" : 3,
   "resturant_id" : 1,
    "created_at": "2019-08-13 23:32:40",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-14 00:01:16",    
   "products" :[
     {"product_id" : 4  },
    {"product_id" : 6 }
]

}
```

it updating just the ID of product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
public function UpdateOrder(Request $request , $id){

    $order =  Order::find($id);
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->user_id = $request->user_id;  
    $order->resturant_id = $request->resturant_id; 

    $order->save();
    $product = Product ::find($request->products);
    $order->product()->sync($product);

}
```

I don't know if it will update the `$product` also but this will update the `$order`

Hope it helps